# Web Application apache tomcat service is getting restarted due to tomcat JVM crash

Tags: java, tomcat7

We are running web application hosted on tomcat7. But service is getting stopped due to JVM crash. Here is stack trace for JVM crash.

```
Stack: [0x3aa40000,0x3aa60000],  sp=0x3aa5fb64,  free space=126k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [tcnative-1.dll+0x6da6]
J 2140  org.apache.tomcat.jni.Poll.poll(JJ[JZ)I (0 bytes) @ 0x0133ce94 [0x0133cde0+0xb4]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 2140  org.apache.tomcat.jni.Poll.poll(JJ[JZ)I (0 bytes) @ 0x0133ce50 [0x0133cde0+0x70]
J 2139% C2 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller.run()V (2291 bytes) @ 0x012f4420 [0x012f3f80+0x4a0]
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Here is header part of it.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x35a86da6, pid=2756, tid=4612
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b19) (build 1.7.0_65-b19)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [tcnative-1.dll+0x6da6]
```

We have found out that one just before crash there is only thread running from our own application but not sure how this thread will cause tomcat crash. We are trying simulation locally. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Seems you use a native library `tcnative-1.dll` that causes the crash.

Comment: Is there any way we can run tomcat without using tcnative-1.dll? What would be consequences of not using this dll? I read somewhere this dll is optional but I don't know how to disable it and what would impact of disabling this dll? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this properties:

`org.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES=true`

to tomcat/conf/catalina.properties file and restart the application server according to http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/KnownIssues#ImageIOIssues.

Comment: Above solution is not working in our case. We still able to see crash even after applying above workaround.is there anything other that we can try?